# How to ignore specific files in Atom/JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint, atom-editor

I'm on Windows using `Atom 1.0.0`, `linter-jshint 0.1.7` and am working on a web project. I'm using gulp, so I have some javascript files that are concatenated (this is why I can't simply add `/* jshint ignore:start */` to the file, because it's overwritten after calling gulp later).

I added a `.jshintignore` file to my projects root folder, but it doesn't seem to work (although, according to the `linter-jshint` sources, there are some lines committed to load the `.jshintignore` file with `--exclude-path`.

The content of my `.jshintignore` file is:

```
public/js/bundle.js
public/js/vendor.js
```

edit: Contents of gulp is as simple as:

```
mix.scripts([
    'jquery.js',
    'vue.js'
], 'vendor.js');
```

Because my linter settings dont apply to jquery or vue, I get tons of errors slowing down the application. Adding `/* jshint ignore:start */` helps, but I for one really don't want to edit the vendor files or the merged one.

Comment: sorry - changed the title.

Comment: This issue is being worked in the core linter. We need your ideas. See https://github.com/atom-community/linter/issues/744

Comment: Could you post the code of your gulp task?